# Change ImageView and Text of DrawerLayout template in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am using the DrawerLayout template from within Android Studio. I'm trying to figure out how to change the image and text in the header through code.

I tried finding the "id's" from within the navigation view like so:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    usrTag = (TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.usrName);
    tagrEmail = (TextView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.usrEmail);
    tagrPic = (CircleImageView)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.usrImg);
```

But I get a null pointer exception if I try to change the text or anything else of any of those views. I've also tried with just findViewById but that didn't work either. Any ideas? Because I'm frustrated and stumped. I assumed that all I had to do was find the layout by id and then find the views by id from within that layout but that hasn't been the case.

**Some Clarification**

In Android Studio, if you select File>New>New Project and go through the wizard and choose Navigation View Activity you will see exactly what I am referring to.
Main class is an Activity. That default created activity references a layout called nav_header_main.xml which looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/usrImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usrName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usrEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the MainActivity class there is no reference to the layout. I tried creating a reference to the layout and then finding the views within that layout using findViewById but I still got null pointer exception.

Comment: Yes I've double and triple checked if those id's exist and they do.

Comment: Are you using a fragment or an activity ?

Comment: @Snoobie I am using the default Navigation View Activity when you choose new project in android studio. I am not trying to access any of the menu items. If you look at my comment below the first answer, you'll see what layout I'm referring to.

Comment: @SteveC. Check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getHeaderView() method to get items in header layout of NavigationView.

```
 View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
 TextView usrName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.usrName);
 TextView usrEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.usrEmail);
 CircleImageView usrImg = (CircleImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.usrImg);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! Feel like I just had a car lifted off my brain. I feel so relieved right now. So thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To get view for single item in drawer menu use:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id);
```

In your **nav_header_main.xml** used by drawer ( example single item):

```
        <item
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:title="Title"
        android:id="@+id/your_menu_item_id" //here id
        />
```

To get View from item:

```
 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id).getActionView();
```

**IMPORTANT**. Be sure your drawer was inflated.

**Change icon and title of item:**

navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id).setTitle("new title");
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id).setIcon(icon_drawable_here);

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but if you go to Android Studio>new project>Navigation Drawer Activity you will see in the layouts folder "nav_header_main.xml" That is where I am trying to change the imageview and textview with code.

Comment: I added how to change icon and text in menu element. So i think this is what you need.

Comment: I appreciate the help but if you look at the layout, there are no menu items.

Comment: Please paste xml for the drawer.